# Succinctly naming an Either object

Tags: c#, naming

I have an object that wraps an `Either<T,T[]>`. It can only be either a single instance of `T` or an array of `T[]` but I don't know at compile time. What do I name the class, and what do I name an instance for example `Either<string,string[]>`? I want to describe it as short as possible.

```
//class name
SingularOrArray //too long
SingleOrMultiple //too long
AnyOfT //not descriptive enough

//instance name (string)
SingleOrMultipleString //too long
StringOrStrings //clumsy
AnyString //not descriptive enough
```

Comment: How do you plan to use that object? That could help find some ideas for naming. E.g. like composite pattern?

Comment: What @BernhardHiller said, from this description the only thing we know it does would indeed be "Either". If the `Either` has some _other behaviour depending on the amount of elements_, then that behaviour might give you a good name. However, I'm rather thinking this might be an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). After all, _an array with only one element is still a valid array_ and I can't think of anything `Either<>` could do that an array couldn't with  `if(stringArray.Length == 1)`.

Comment: Indeed - if the difference between one and mutliple contained elements does not affect behavior, it shouldn't be mentioned in the name. In this case, it would be an implementation detail the user should not need to care about.

Comment: It has a function `Match(Action<T> singleMatch, Action<T[]> arrayMatch>`. I unfortunately cannot use only an array and check `if(stringArray.Length == 1)` because I want to capture the difference between an array of length 1 and a single value. It indicates that "there could have been more than one element but in this case there was only one", or "there was only one element and there was never an option that there could be more".

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a reason why that matters...

Comment: Well, without going into the intricacies of my business case, the question remains.

Comment: its a pity you cant use () in names otherwise object(s) child(ren) maybe you could use underscore to represent the convention child_ren?

Comment: Yes it's too bad... Maybe something like `Element_s` could work

Comment: Your naming constraints are pretty severe.  The difference between your "not descriptive enough" example and your "too long" examples is nine characters.

Comment: Are you going to handle array of size 1 the same as singleton, or is the singleton really differentiated?  If you're going to treat them the same anyway, I'd suggest wrapping the singleton with an array instead of an Either.

Answer (score 1):

> It **can only be either a single instance of T or an array of T[]**
>   but I don't know at compile time

You don't need to have both cases in your class then. Instead abstract their behaviour to the interface and have two implementations of that interface. One for single object and one for an array.

```
public interface IDataOf<T>
{
    void Match(Action<T> match);
    void Match(Action<T[]> match);
}

public class SingleOf<T>
{
    private readonly T _data;

    public SingleOf(T data) => _data = data;

    void Match(Action<T> match)
    {
        match(_data);
    }

    void Match(Action<T[]> match)
    {
        // do nothing or throw an exception
    }
}

public class MultipleOf<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _data;

    public MultipleOf(T[] data) => _data = data;

    void Match(Action<T> match)
    {
        // do nothing or throw an exception
    }
    void Match(Action<T[]> match)
    {
        match(_data);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
Action<string> singleMatch = item => { };
Action<string[]> multipleMatch = items => { };

var text = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
IDataOf<string> lines = new MultipleOf<string>(text);
lines.Match(multipleMatch);

var anotherText = "only one";
IDataOf<string> sentence = new SingleOf<string>(anotherText);
sentence.Match(singleMatch);
```

Names of the classes should be based on their behavior.
Names of the variables should be based on their usage, easy to read and understand in the current context.

If you still want to have class with both options, name `SingularOrArray` is good enough and **is not too long**.